# Putting balls into boxes where balls and/or boxes are distinguishable

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Part (a) How many ways are there to put $4$ balls into $3$ boxes, given that the balls are not distinguished and neither are the boxes?

Part (b) How many ways are there to put $2$ white balls and $2$ black balls into $3$ boxes, given that balls of the same color are indistinguishable, but the boxes are distinguishable?

I am not sure how distinguished and indistinguishable makes a difference in the question and I have no clue how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (a), these are (unordered) partitions of $4$ into $3$ parts where parts can be $0.$ To ensure that you hit all possibilities, tackle three cases: exactly $2,1,$ or $0$ parts with nothing. There cannot be three parts with nothing. If exactly $2$ parts have nothing, the only possibility is $4+0+0.$ If exactly $1$ part has nothing, the possibilities are $3+1+0$ and $2+2+0.$ If exactly $0$ parts have nothing, then each part has at least $1.$ This means the remaining one gets assigned somewhere and the only possibility is $2+1+1.$ So the answer is $4.$

For the second part, treat white balls and black balls separately. Doing either one will let you square it to get the answer thanks to the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). For white balls, there are $$\binom{2+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{4}{2}=6$$ possibilities, so the answer is $6^2=36.$ This is using [sticks and stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: I believe part (b) is wrong. The question states that there are $3$ boxes, and I think you are considering only $2$.

Comment: @ThomasBladt thanks, you are right that I misread $3$ boxes for $2$ boxes. I have fixed the solution.